# Find a string into each file of a folder with for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, find

I try to find a string "blabla" inside a file. If I find the string I replace it with "bloblo", if not do nothing. And I want to do this operation for all the files that I have in a folder.

When I apply the script on one file, it works well. When I use a for loop it doesn't work. it does not enter inside the for loop

Here is my script:

```
    set "Var1=blabla"
    set "Var2=bloblo"

FOR %%i IN (C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\TEST\*.txt) DO (      
        find /c "%Var1%" %%i
        if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto notfound
        call PathFile\FUNCTION_REPLACE.cmd %Var1% %Var2% %%i

        :notfound
)
```

I use a script "Function_replace" to replace the values, here is the script:

```
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "search=%~1"
Set "replace=%2"
Set "File=%3"

For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=]" %%A In ('Find /V /N ""^<"%File%"^&Break^>"%File%"'
)Do (Set "line=%%B"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    (If Not "%%B"=="" (Echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!)Else Echo()>>"%File%"
    EndLocal)
```

I used to use directly the call of my replace function for each files of my folder. But it takes a long time to go inside each file. That's why I want to check before going inside each file, if the string exists or not (by using find /c).

Can you spot where is the issue coming from?

Comment: you have a [delayed expansion problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028). If the loop isn't executed at all, there are no matching files. Oh - and you can't use labels inside a (command block).

Comment: Your example seems a little too simplistic. If you search for the string in one file then a simple found or not found message could be useful. If you were searching through all of the files in a directory, then those messages serve no purpose unless each message also shows the file searched with respect to that message. Can you please explain what the task really is? because knowing that would determine the most appropriate method on which to base possible solutions.

Comment: `findstr /m "blabla" "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\TEST\*.txt" gives you the names of the files that contain the string. Is that useful to you?

Comment: `for %%a in (*) do @findstr "E" "%%a" >nul && (echo found in %%a) || (echo not found in %%a)` may also help.

Comment: I gave more details about why I need these labels inside my for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your latest edit, here's an example which sends only the files containing the string to be replaced, to the sub-function:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "search=%~1"
Set "replace=%~2"
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('FindStr /LIMP "%search%" *.*')Do Call :Sub "%%A"
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Set "File=%~1"
For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=]" %%A In ('Find /V /N ""^<"%File%"^&Break^>"%File%"'
)Do (Set "line=%%B"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    (If Not "%%B"=="" (Echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!)Else Echo()>>"%File%"
    EndLocal)
```

*Please note that the `FindStr` command uses only example options, whilst the `/M` option is important to this solution you should check the output from `FindStr /?` to determine which of the others you would consider the most appropriate.*

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply list all files that has the string and exclude the files that don't? That seems like a more obvious plan to me:

```
@echo off
set "search=blabla"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /m %search% "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TEST\*.txt"') do (
  echo found "%search%" in "%%~fi"
)
```

If you want to still show files that does not contain the path, then @stephan already posted a comment on how to, no need for me to repeat.